# Batch File Xcopy Error

Tags: batch-file

Need some help here I am stuck. I copied a piece out of my batch file that doesn't work. Anyway when It gets to the Xcopy command I get a Error Invalid Number of parameters. I have taken out all switches still get the same thing. If I put this command in another batch file that just has this command it runs fine. I have tried running as Admin as well I have tried it with and without Quotes. I am stuck, Anyone have any input?

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4\EasyDent4.exe" (
echo File Exists. Renaming file...
goto Continue1
)
Echo file doesnt exist. Creating file from copy.
goto Continue2
)
:Continue1
rename "C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4\EasyDent4.exe" EasyDent4.exe.bak (
Echo Renamed completed.
goto Continue2
)
:Continue2
xcopy /I /G EasyDent4.exe C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4\ (  
Echo Copied File to C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4\
goto Continue3
)
:Continue3
echo completed


pause
```

Comment: The opening parenthesis behind the `xcopy` command line makes no sense; place it in the next line, or remove the whole pair...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "(" after the xcopy. Windows believes that the "(" is part of the commands parameters therefore it says invalid amount of paramaters because the parameters given is 1 more than the maximum amount of allowed parameters. I hope this makes sense. If you really need the "(" then make a new line under xcopy and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

The opening parenthesis on the xcopy line wasn't the only thing wrong, you had also done the same thing on your rename line.

It is my belief that you intended to create a block of code upon the success of rename and another upon the success of xcopy. For you to have done that, you'd have needed to use **`&&`**:

```bat
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4\EasyDent4.exe" (
    ECHO File Exists. Renaming file...
) ELSE (
    ECHO file doesnt exist. Creating file from copy.
    GOTO Continue2
)

:Continue1
RENAME "C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4\EasyDent4.exe" EasyDent4.exe.bak && (
    ECHO Renamed completed.
)

:Continue2
XCOPY /I /G EasyDent4.exe C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4\ && (  
    ECHO Copied File to C:\EasyDent4\EdpV4
)

:Continue3
ECHO completed
```